# Ubuntu does not show the maximize button in electron

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem with Ubuntu, and when we compile the Electron project we can not see the maximize screen button. By "compile" I want to refer to a `electron build => ng build --configuration=dev && electron`. I have Electron version 4.0.1.

Sample photo:

[image]

My `main.js` is the following:

```js
fu let win: any window() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
      // width: 1024,
      // height: 768,
      minWidth: 1024,
      minHeight: 768,
      // center: true,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      },
      resizable: true
  });
  // win = new Browser Window({ fullscreen: true })
```

I tried explicitly setting `maximizable: true`.

Comment: Can not recreate with minimal build... using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. maybe open a isse on [GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Removing **minHeight** and **minWidth** solved this case for me. Yet to explore the reason behind it, though!

Answer (score -2):

Try (in terminal)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close,'
```

moving the : to the end (like this gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'minimize,maximize,close:') and then restarting to see if they reappear for you.

Let us know.

Comment: No, with this command it does not work, and I have gnome installed